# Not understanding nested resources using the Grape API gem in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-grape, grape-api

Here is what my API looks like:

```
module ServiceRequests
  class API < Grape::API
    version 'v1', using: :path
    format :json

    namespace :companies do
      params do
        requires :company_id, type: Integer, desc: "A Company Id"
      end

      resource :service_requests do
        get :all do
          Company.find(params[:company_id]).service_requests
        end
      end
    end

  end
end
```

I am trying to make calls like this: `http://localhost/v1/companies/:company_id/service_requests/all` but when I make this call, I am receiving the error of `No route matches [GET] "/v1/companies/1/service_requests/all"`

Working Code:

```
module ServiceRequests
  class API < Grape::API
    version 'v1', using: :path
    format :json

    resource :companies do

      params do
        requires :company_id, type: Integer, desc: "A Company Id"
      end

      route_param :company_id do
        resource :service_requests do
          get do
            Company.find(params[:company_id]).service_requests
          end
        end
      end

    end

  end
end
```

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried doing this?

```
namespace 'companies/:company_id' do
  resource :service_requests do
    get :all do
      Company.find(params[:company_id]).service_requests
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Nice, I hadn't tried that! I am updating my question with I wound up doing for it to work

Comment: Cool, didn't know `route_param` was available in the DSL.